# c++ vector push_back need assistance

Tags: c++

Question is very easy but i forgot to use c++ and don't know where else to ask.

I have question regarding vectors in c++: when i make vector with objects and when i try to push_back new object on vector i get some wierd error. Can u help me and say how should i use push_back (on object?) so it works. Thanks!

I have .h class:

```
class x{
    public:
        x();

        double cpuGHz;
        int hddGB;
        char brand[25];
};

and have main class:

#include "Racunalo.h"

#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <string.h>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

int main()
{

    int n,i;

    double cpu;
    int hdd;
    char bra[25];
    vector<Racunalo> vec;

    Racunalo rac;

    cin >> n;

    for (i=0; i<n; i++)
        {
            cin >> bra;
            cin >> hdd;
            cin >> cpu;

            strcpy(rac.brand, bra);
            rac.hddGB = hdd;
            rac.cpuGHz = cpu;

            vec[i].push_back(rac); // this line is "rotten"
        }
```

Comment: tried vec.push_back(rac)? vec[i] gives you a Racunalo-object, which probably doesn't have a method named push_back.

Comment: HDD, CPU and a BRA is all you need :)

Comment: Unless the conveniently omitted type `Racunalo` is also a container supporting `push_back`, this won't compile at all, and your class `x` isn't used whatsoever in your posted `main()`. For future reference, always *post real code **and** the real error message.*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Replace

```
vec[i].push_back(rac);
```

with

```
vec.push_back(rac);
```

Good luck

Comment: Kristijan Delivuk may I ask what was the reason that you decided this answer is more informative to you?

Answer (score 1):

```
vec[i].push_back(rac);
^^^^^^^
a reference to Recunalo object
```

`vec[i]` gives you an element of your  `vector` (a reference to element), so you cannot `push_back` to it (unless it is object of class with `push_back` function). Here `vec[i]` refers to `Racunalo` object. `std::vector::push_back` is a member function of `vector`, so we call it on the object this way:

```
vec.push_back( rac);
^^^^
std::vector<Recunalo>
```

[std::vector::push_back](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/push_back)

Answer (score 0):

Vector is just like an array except that it can grow dynamically.

push_back is a method that adds at the end of the container. If you create a vector like vector a(10) and then do a push_back you are inserting at the 11th place since all the first 10 places are initialized with 0. So, to be helpful it is ideal to create a vector like vector a, without any size, and then using push_back to insert at the end.

vector a;
a.push_back(5);